# How to assign a UserName value at creation

Tags: username

I want to allow users to register on my site. However, I want to assign the UserName value so that it is in a particular format and so that the user cannot change it. The format will incorporate the UserID value along with a prefix, therefore I do not need to see if the UserName is already being used because this value should be unique.

Can this be accomplished with a filter and corresponding action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the username need to be in a particular format? And how are users registering? Is it via the normal `wp-login.php` method? Or are you using a custom registration form?

Comment: Usernames can't be changed by default so you are fine on that front. So yes basically you should be able to hook a function on the `user_register` action and update the username to the desired format within that based on any user information provided (eg. ID, name etc.) 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Comment: Although this question was posed more than two years ago, I am only responding to it now. Thanks to those who did provide a response.